# Calling WCF service with jquery and parameters synchronously

Tags: .net, jquery, wcf

I am calling a .NET WCF service from Ajax like this:

```
result = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: BaseUrl + "Services/YucataService.svc/SetGameStatusSecure",
    data: "{'gameID':'" + gameID + "','pid':'" + pid + "','status':'" + newStatus + "','origStatus':'" + oldStatus + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 20000
});
```

The server part looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
public void SetGameStatusSecure(int gameID, int pid, string status, string origStatus)
{
   ... magic stuff happens
}
```

It works well.

Now, I would like to call the service synchronously. The only change I do is to add "async: false". 
The call return with status 500 (=internal server error).

Do I have to configure the WCF service differently to allow sync calls?

Before I switched to WCF I used an .asmx service to call synchronously and I didn't have any issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to hit the backend, first try to have a break point at the backend and see if you can hit the breakpoint. Check where it is failing

Comment: Breakpoint is not hit when calling synchronously. So, WCF is denying the call before my code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think by default WCF accepts Synchronous calls. If you want to make it asynchronous, you need make sure you check  “Generate asynchronous operations” under Advanced tab. (at the time of adding service reference). Be default, this check box is always unchecked.